# Kendo UI grid : Filtering based on a custom field and having a pager

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a problem when using a CustomField ( Name() ) within a filter that is using ds.query in order to filter, sort and reinitialize the pager for a Grid, I have created a simplified example that illustrates the problem clearly: https://jsfiddle.net/juliemontreuil/4Ls4fb19/32/

> ```
> var PageSize = 5;
>
> var data1 = [...];
>
> var $grid = $("#BTGrid");
> var sort = [{
>   field: "company",
>   dir: "asc"
> }];
>
> var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
>   data: data1,
>   schema: {
>     model: {
>       id: "Id",
>       fields: {
>         Id: {},
>         Firstname: {},
>         LastName: {},
>         company: {},
>         email: {}
>       },
>       Name: function() {
>         return this.get("Firstname") + " " + this.get("LastName");
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   sort: sort,
>   pageSize: PageSize //page size
> });
> $grid.kendoGrid({
>   dataSource: dataSource,
>   columns: [{
>     field: "Name()",
>     title: "Name",
>   }, {
>     field: "company",
>     title: "Company"
>   }, {
>     field: "email",
>     title: "Email"
>   }],
>   scrollable: false,
>   pageable: true, //enable paging
>   resizable: true,
>   sortable: {
>     allowUnsort: false
>   }
> });
>
> $('.grid-filter').off('keyup').on('keyup', function() {
>   var ds = $("#BTGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
>   // debugger;
>   var filterText = $(this).val();
>   var $filter = {
>     logic: "or",
>     filters: [{
>       field: "company",
>       operator: "contains",
>       value: filterText
>     }, {
>       field: "email",
>       operator: "contains",
>       value: filterText
>     }, {
>       field: "Name()",
>       operator: "contains",
>       value: filterText
>     }]
>   };
>   ds.query({
>     filter: $filter,
>     sort: [{
>       field: "company",
>       dir: "asc"
>     }],
>     page: 1,
>     pageSize: PageSize
>   });
> });
> ```

, if you modify the var PageSize = 5; to var PageSize = 25; the filter will function correctly because the data array contains only 24 items, please advise .

Answer (score 2):

I have been testing your code and I note that the Name function is the one is failing.

So I made this for you:
[Solution whitout Name()](https://jsfiddle.net/ericklanford/24mct4x3/1/)

Note that now the kendogrid use a template:

```
$grid.kendoGrid({
  dataSource: dataSource,
  columns: [{
    title: "Name",
    template: '#= Firstname# #= LastName#',
  }, {
    field: "company",
    title: "Company"
  }, {
    field: "email",
    title: "Email"
  }],
  scrollable: false,
  pageable: true, //enable paging
  resizable: true,
  sortable: {
    allowUnsort: false
  }
});
```

..Yes,..of course,.. now you are going to say: "How cant filter by the full name (Firstname + Lastname)?".

Well, in order to fix that situation you can declare a property (FulName) inside "data1" and then use that property in the grid and inside the filter too.
Hope this ideas works for you. :)